# How to use relative urls in contentscriptfile?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

It says in firefox add-on sdk documentation about `contentStyleFile` option of `page-mod` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) that:

> In earlier versions of this module, you couldn't use relative URLs in
>   stylesheets loaded in this way, and you had to use a workaround. In
>   current versions this has been fixed, and the workaround is no longer
>   needed.

However it doesn't mention how to do that, i tried to include a local image from the `data` folder inside my addon:

```
element
{
    background: url(data/image.jpeg);
}
```

But nothing happened..

How can i reference an image url inside my contentStyleFile without using javascript?

Comment: Never mind i just figured it out, the `contentStyleFile` was inside the data folder, so i had to use `image.jpeg` instead of `data/image.jpeg`. The url is relative to the css file.

Comment: Move it to answer man. I didnt know u could do that, so its nice.

Comment: It's a new feature i guess, i remember using javascript as workaround few months ago. I added an answer below.

Comment: It's been around for quite a few months, and yes it's nice. Similar to how icon paths are relative when creating buttons since Firefox 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs in the `contentScriptFile` are relative to the `contentScriptFile` itself.

In my example the `contentScriptFile (style.css)` is inside the `data` folder, so to reference the image `image.jpeg` all i had to do was:

```
element
{
    background: url(image.jpeg)
}
```